# How can I determine the X & Y coordinates of a row in a TableView in JavaFX 8

Tags: tableview, javafx-8

I would like to pop up a node relative to a selected row in a TableView.  The UI that we are following uses an Edit Button to open the pop over, and I would like to place it either under the row or above the row depending on where the row is in the TableView.

I can't seem to find a way to locate the X & Y coordinates of the row without clicking on the row.

Since my application needs to be fully keyboard navigable, I need to be able to determine that location from a selected row, even if it was selected via the keyboard.

I.e. something like this

```
myTableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().location() or something like that.
```

I have looked at a couple of examples here, but none seems to provide enough detail on how to get the coordinates based on the click somewhere else on the screen.

Thanks!

Comment: When you say X & Y coordinates, do you mean the (x,y) pair corresponding to the pixel location within the scene or the screen? or are you referring to the x,y coordinates as they would be within a matrix? (aka: table), in which case, do you want the cell location or the row location? x coordinate doesn't make much sense when talking about whole rows (assuming x on the horizontal)...

Comment: I would like the X,Y coordinates in relation to the screen that the table is presented on.  So that I can determine where the row starts (in the event the table is not left most on the screen) and where it is in relation to the size of the screen.  That way I can place my overlay at the left of the table below the row that is currently selected.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something along these lines:

```
TableView<T> table = ... ;

ObjectProperty<TableRow<T>> lastSelectedRow = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
table.setRowFactory(tableView -> {
    TableRow<T> row = new TableRow<T>();
    row.selectedProperty().addListener((obs, wasSelected, isNowSelected) -> {
        if (isNowSelected) {
            lastSelectedRow.set(row);
        } 
    }
    return row ;
});
```

Then at any time `lastSelectedRow.get()` will return the actual node representing the last selected row, or `null` if no row has been selected (under the current implementation of `TableView`'s behavior, I don't think this will happen). You can then use the various `getBoundsIn*()` methods, perhaps combined with `localTo*()` methods, to get the location of the row when you need it: for example

```
TableRow<?> row = lastSelectedRow.get();
Bounds bounds = row.localToScreen(row.getBoundsInLocal());
```

will give the bounds of the last selected row relative to the screen coordinates.

Strange things may happen if the user selects something with the mouse, then scrolls the selected row out of view; but then you need to figure out how to deal with that however you get the coordinates.

Comment: Must the line 'selectedRow.set(row);' be 'lastSelectedRow.set();' ?

Comment: Yes, sorry; I changed it as it wasn't robust the first way and didn't update that line. Now fixed.